# Moving Solution from Sharepoint 2010 to Sharepoint 2013 Problem with Remote SharePoint site connections

Tags: migration

I moving a Visual Web Part from Sharepoint 2010 to Sharepoint 2013. The web Part is connected with same of lists. I moved them almost all. But after moved Webpart i getting this error:

```
Error   5   Error occurred in deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application Pool': Remote SharePoint site connections are not supported.
Parameter name: project
```

But I dont connecting with any **Remote SharePoint site connections**. Why I getting this error ?

Comment: Have you checked the site url in the solution properties?

Comment: Yes the Url is good. The domain adres of the server. That is something else.

Answer (score 0):

I find out a Solution On it. I have got not configure my Sharepoint Developer Web Appication as server site. Not as 127.0.0.1 :)